# How to allow a mouse click close to an element?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, usability

Long ago at a conference talk on React I saw the presenter add something to his code that allowed you to click-drag a divider on the screen by getting to within a certain number of pixels of it, rather than have click exactly on it.

It's a handy concept for improving usability, though I don't know what it is called. Adding 'slop' perhaps? Anyway I completely forget how he did it, presumably using some padding approach. Does anyone know what this practice is called and how to implement it? I assume it was something he achieved it with CSS but am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vanilla js to do that. Using `element.getBoundingClientRect()` to retrieve the element's offset relative to body and comparing with the actual `mouseX` and `mouseY`(in the click moment of course) you now know the distance between the element and the click, now add some logic like: Case distance < acceptable offset then do some side effect.